# How to retain datatype and decimals after cast - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

This must be a silly question but I'm unable to find a proper way to handle the below scenario.
My objective is to take a number in varchar column and cast it to decimal. However, I also need to make sure that the decimal places remain intact. How do I achieve this and make sure the datatype will remain to DECIMAL(13,3).

```
 select TO_CHAR(CAST(11.0001 AS DECIMAL(13,3)) ,9999999999.999) from dual;  -- O/p : 11.000; Datatype : VARCHAR2

 select TO_CHAR(CAST(0.0001 AS DECIMAL(13,3)) ,9999999999.999) from dual; -- O/p : .000; Datatype : VARCHAR2

 select CAST(11.0001 AS DECIMAL(13,3)) from dual; -- O/p : 11; Datatype : DECIMAL(13,3)

 select CAST(0.0001 AS DECIMAL(13,3)) from dual; -- O/p : 0; Datatype : DECIMAL(13,3)
```

What I am looking for as an output would be :

```
Input : 11.0001  VARCHAR(40)  Output : 11.000 DECIMAL(13,3)
Input : 0.0001 VARCHAR(10)    Output : 0.000 DECIMAL(13,3)
Input : 18     VARCHAR(40)    Output : 18    DECIMAL(13,3)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Oracle, but I would think the display of decimal zero's is just a display setting. And I don't think it's possible to show the zeroes of one value, but not of another value.

Comment: If you are talking about NLS Parameters. I just checked and my session parameters for NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS is ".,". Not sure how to work with this.

Comment: @SDR . . . You don't get to control how may decimals are shown for the `decimal` type.  If you need that control, use strings.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Do you mean that even the first 2 scenarios  from my Output are not possible?

Comment: @SDR . . . You can use `number` and *insert* the values as numbers with the number of decimal points that you want.  I don't know if there is a way to have variable precision otherwise.  If what you care about is what it looks like, then format on output, add a computed column, or store as a string.

Comment: @GordonLinoff.. I don't have the flexibility to store as string as these go into another database where the datatype should match to the destination. However, I think I changed  the way the function works which will only accept the numbers which match the precision and scale and then do a CAST. That should help in my current scenario. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're asking the right question. Numbers do not have decimal places. 18 is the same as 18.0 is the same as 18.00. You can format a number, which gives you a *string* formatted in the desired way, with however many digits you want.

If you are taking these `VARCHAR2`'s and converting them to numerics, but want to know how they were previously displayed, then you are losing information. Why do you need to convert these to decimals in the first place? Are you just trying to take things with 4 digits of precision and remove anything past the 3rd digit?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.. Seems like I am trying to achieve the wrong thing. I've changed my code to error out those values that dont have the correct decimal places and then did a CAST for the rest. This still held  the decimal places intact.